# How to get my dates out of local storage and set them without the time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, date

I have an event form that where I get information put it in the localstorage (I cannot use an API) and I want to take the startdate and enddate out of localstorage, change them so they appear as dd-mm-yyyy (not yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z) The issue is getting them out of the array and setting them. I have no idea where to begin....

Here is my JavaScript/jQuery:

```
.controller("Events", function($scope, $location) {

    let URL = "https://morning-castle-91468.herokuapp.com/";
    $scope.authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
    $scope.username = localStorage.getItem("username");

    $scope.events = [];
    let lastEvent = 0;

    while (localStorage.getItem("event"+lastEvent)){

        $scope.events.unshift(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("event"+lastEvent)));
        lastEvent++;
    }

    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("event")) || [];

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        if ($scope.eventForm.$valid) {
            $scope.event.username = $scope.username;

            localStorage.setItem("event"+lastEvent, JSON.stringify($scope.event));
        }
    };

})
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row eventcontent" ng-repeat="event in events">
    <div class="col-xs-12 eventpost">
        <div class="row-flex">
            <div class="col-xs-8 ">
                <h4>{{ event.title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 ">
                <h4>{{ event.name }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <td>{{ event.description }}</td>
                <br />
                <br />
                <p>{{ event.address }} <br /> {{ event.country }}</p>
                <br />
                <p>{{ event.status }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <p>{{ event.startdate }} {{ event.enddate }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to Angular.

But anyway, it looks like you are creating an array `events` having all the previously stored `event`.

You use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) which is adding each `event` at the beginning of the array. The result probably is like so (for 2 elements):

**$scope.events:**

```
[ // That is event1
  {
    name:someValue,
    description:someValue,
    address:someValue,
    country:someValue,
    status:someValue,
    startdate:"yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z",
    enddate:"yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z"
  },
// That is event0
  {
    //Same structure as above...
  }
]
```

**So now,**, assuming you wish to have the last `event`, which is the first element in the `events` array, and the structure is as above, I would try:

```
// Retreive the dates from the first array element... Only the part before the "T" in each string.
var retreived_start = $scope.events[0].startdate.split("T")[0];
var retreived_end = $scope.events[0].enddate.split("T")[0];

// Split the date by the "-" to re-order...
var start_parts = retreived_start.split("-");
var end_parts = retreived_start.split("-");

// YYYY-MM-DD results
var formatted_start = start_parts[2] +"-"+ start_parts[1] +"-"+ start_parts[0]; 
var formatted_end = end_parts[2] +"-"+ end_parts[1] +"-"+ end_parts[0];

// Place it in your Angular controller array (? -- I'm unsure here)
$scope.event.startdate = formatted_start;
$scope.event.enddate = formatted_end;
```

**But now that you've modified the `event` array**... It may be stored as "formatted"... So be aware of that!

---

That line is doing absolutely nothing: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("event")) || [];`, since not assigned to a variable, you can safely remove it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it. And JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("event")) || [];
is doing something (seeing as it breaks when I remove it). It is always called upon when the controller is, its saying that if there is information in it then parse OR create an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

To get Data from localstroage which will be an **JSON ArrayList** then,

```
var retrievedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("event"+lastEvent));            
var setDateFormat = $filter('date')(new Date((retrievedData[1].substr(6)), 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
```